# How can i start service on boot device in android sdk 29 or least?

Tags: android, service

Hye, I'm trying to start service on boot in my android device SDK 29, 30. But face issue to start service.
My code runs fine below SDK 29, like in Android oreo or Android 5

My Code in menifest is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <receiver android:name=".awc.BootReceiver" android:exported="false" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".awc.AWC_Service"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":ServiceProcess" />
```

Code is receiver is:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(context.getApplicationContext());
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            if (!prefManager.getBoolean("AWC_Disabled")) {
                Intent service = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), AWC_Service.class);
                intent.putExtra("StopSer", false);
                // context.startService(service);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    context.startForegroundService(service);
                } else {
                    context.startService(service);
                }
                Log.e("Phone Restart", "AWS Service start");
            }
            Log.e("Phone Restart", "AWS Service start1");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is issue ?

Comment: issue is this boot broadcast receiver is not called in SDK 29 or 30

Comment: i am still using it very well in sdk 30. you can see error in logcat after device boot using `adb logcat k9:V *:S AndroidRuntime:E`

Comment: hey Can you send me your source code

Comment: you still haven't solved it?. how did you start your service in activity